# php, mySQL & AJAX: Unable to use sessions across the scripts in the same domain

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have the following pages: page1.php, page2.php and page3.php. Code in each of them is as below

**CODE:**

**page1.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
    $('#imgID').upload({
        submit_to_url: "page2.php",
        file_name: 'myfile1',
        description : "Image",
        limit : 1,      
        file_types : "*.jpg",

    })
}); 

</script>

<body>
<form action="page3.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="frm1" id="frm1">
//Some other text fields
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
```

**page2.php**

```
<?php session_start();
$a = $_SESSION['a'];
$b = $_SESSION['b'];
$c = $_SESSION['c'];

$res = mysql_query("SELECT col FROM table WHERE col1 = $a AND col2 = $b AND col3 = $c LIMIT 1");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($res);
echo $num_rows; //echos 0 when in fact it should have been 1 because the data in the Session exists.

//Ok let's proceed further
//... Do some stuff...
//Store some more values and create new session variables (and assume that page1.php is going to be able to use it)
$_SESSION['d'] = 'd';
$_SESSION['e'] = 'e';
$_SESSION['f'] = 'f';

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $file)) 
{ 
  echo "success"; 
} 
else 
{
 echo "error ".$_FILES['file']['error'];
}

?>
```

**page3.php**

```
<?php session_start(); 
if( isset($_POST['submit']) )
{
  //These sessions are non-existent although the AJAX request 
  //to page2.php may have created them when called via AJAX from within page1.php 
  echo $_SESSION['d'].$_SESSION['e'].$_SESSION['f']; ?> 
}
?>
```

1. As the code says it I am posting some info via AJAX call from page1.php to page2.php. page2.php is supposed to be able to use the session values from page1.php i.e. $_SESSION['a'], $_SESSION['b'] and $_SESSION['c'] but it does not. Why? How can I fix this?
2. page2.php is creating some more sessions after some processing is done and a response is sent back to page1.php. The submit button of the form on page1.php is hit and the page gets POST'ed to page3.php. But when the SESSION info that gets created in page2.php is echoed, it's blank signifying that SESSIONS from page2.php are not used. How can I fix this?

I looked over a lot of information and have spent about 50 hours trying to do different things with my scripts before arriving at the above conclusions. My app. is custom made using function (not OOPS) and does not use any PHP frameworks & I am not even about to use any as my knowledge of OOP concepts is limited any many frameworks are object oriented. I came across race conditions, but the solutions provided don't help too much. One more solution of using DB to hold sessions and seek and retrieve from DB is the last thing on my mind and I really want to avoid creating table, coding and maintaining code for a task as simple as just keeping sessions across pages in the same domain.

**So my request is:** Is there a way that I can solve the above problem(s) via simple coding in present conditions?   Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

**EDIT:**
Also I have sensitive information contained in the SESSIONS that I cannot pass back and forth via the pages using GET or POST. So using SESSIONS is really helpful for me. So if any coding can help me achieve this, that would be really helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the SWFUpload documentation:

> *Cookie issue*
>
> On Windows the Non-IE Flash Player
>   plugin (FireFox, Opera, Safari, etc)
>   will send the IE cookies regardless of
>   the browser used. This breaks
>   authentication and sessions for many
>   server-side scripting technologies.
>
> Developers should manually pass
>   Session and Authentication cookie
>   information and manually restore
>   Sessions on the Server Side if they
>   wish to use Sessions
>
> The SWFUpload package contains
>   work-around sample code for PHP and
>   ASP.Net

I suspect SWFUpload causes your problem.

Check if your javascript posts the session_id:

```
new SWFUpload({
   ...
   post_params: {
     "PHPSESSID" : "<?php echo session_id(); ?>"
   }
}
```

And if your PHP script reacts to the sent session_id.

```
if (isset($_POST["PHPSESSID"])) {
    session_id($_POST["PHPSESSID"]);
}
session_start();
```

([session.auto_start](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start) should be disabled in your php.ini or .htaccess)

Comment: Looks like you probably hit the nail on spot. I was experimenting with the scripts that I had at hand and indeed, much to my disappointment that as long as the upload library was being used, the SESSIONS even did not echo out properly. But if I tested the scripts on standalone grounds, then they worked properly. This meant that there was indeed some problem with the library. I am a little unsure of what you mean by checking my javascript for the code that you gave me. Are you asking me to check if it exists or remove if it exists? Please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: I employed the PHP script in mine on page2.php but still that does not work. Looks like they So by any chance did you happen to find out how this can be fixed with the current script?

Answer (score 0):

What is .upload()? Does it come from a library/plugin? If so, what one?

Does the move_uploaded_file() call get executed successfully?

From the events you describe it sounds to me like the form is being submitted straight to page3.

The code you've posted seems very incomplete (missing javascript, missing form fields, missing where $_SESSION members a b and c are set). You should create a minimalistic example and post the complete code.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just wanted to post a quick summary for your questions: 1. .upload does indeed come from a library and that's SWFupload. I just renamed it for test. 2. Yes, move_uploaded_file() does get the file successfully. I am able to see it in the folder. 3. Well yes and no. The submission is pointed to page3.php for the form. The submission to page2.php is via an AJAX call and using a file type to submit a file. So this upload button within the form on page1.php is a standalone btn that when clicked on,makes a post to page2.php & returns an echo success or errror value.

Comment: Also $_SESSION members a b c set are the variables that hold user login info. Since that is sensitive data, I replaced it with samples. Those session variables are created when user logs in and destroyed when user logs out. Does that help fill up at least some of the missing information?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how Flash works when it comes to cookies. If the file is being uploaded through a Flash applet, and the Flash applet doesn't share cookies with the browser, then the session won't get automatically passed.

Instead you'll need to pass session_name() .'='. session_id() as a parameter of the url (GET data). I believe PHP should pick this up automatically. See the session handling section of the PHP manual.

Comment: Although it is Flash that powers a bit of the AJAX frontend, the sessions are created in PHP. Also I am creating the sessions in page2.php based on the file received. So I am holding the file size and other attributes in session so that I can insert them into my DB on page3.php when user actually presses the SUBMIT button on page1.php. Also I wanted to avoid passing data through GET or POST so that the user does not see it and hence provides an additional layer of security to what goes on behind the scenes. So does that help us in moving further ahead?

Comment: +1 for pointing me in the right direction. I considered the cookie information that you gave me and did some experiments to conclude that the library itself has some bugs. Bob has thrown more light on the exact issue. Appreciate all your help.